# lawn sprinkler differentiation problem

Tags: linear-algebra

A lawn sprinkler is constructed in such a
way that $\dfrac{dθ}{dt}$ is constant, where $θ$ ranges between $45^{\circ}$ and $135^{\circ}$. The distance the water travels horizontally is

$$x=\frac{v^2\sin 2θ}{32}$$

where is the speed of the water. Find $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ and explain why
this lawn sprinkler does not water evenly. What part of the
lawn receives the most water?

I differentiated the function $x$ w.r.t. $t$ and I got:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=
\frac{v}{16}
\left( \frac{dv}{dt} \, \sin 2θ+v\cos 2θ \, \frac{dθ}{dt} \right)$$

I would say that the lawn sprinkler does not water evenly because the rate of change of the speed of $v$ is not constant. But I'm not sure how to find where the lawn receives the most water.

Comment: Please provide more information on the specifications.  How is $x$ found.  Why do you believe that $v$ varies with time?

Comment: Agree with @Dr.MV -- if v is the water speed, it should be constant in this problem, no?

Comment: For the question to make sense, it must be about [this kind of sprinkler](http://www.shrubs.co.uk/ekmps/shops/shrubscouk/images/rectangular-lawn-sprinkler-2975-hk-14627-p.gif), not [this kind of sprinkler](http://www.todayshomeowner.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/how-calculate-lawn-irrigation-4.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that **without gravity**, a circular arc (from $45^{\circ}$ to $135^{\circ}$) receives $Av\Delta t$ amount of water in angle $\Delta \theta$ where $A$ is the cross section of the nozzle.  If $\displaystyle \frac{d\theta}{dt}=$ constant, the water is distributed uniformly over the arc.

In this case, there's $Av\Delta t$ amount of water landing on the ground within length $\Delta x$

Assuming uniform $v$,
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{v^{2}}{16} \cos 2\theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

which is $\theta$ dependent and hence not uniform/even.

For maximal the amount of water receiving, 
$\displaystyle \left| Av\frac{dt}{dx} \right|=\left| \frac{Av}{dx/dt} \right|$ should be the **largest**.

This achieves when $\cos 2\theta=0$ or $\theta=45^{\circ}$ or $135^{\circ}$.

That is at $\displaystyle x=\pm \frac{v^{2}}{32}$ which is the maximal range of projectile.

See the sprinkle shower with $6^{\circ}$ intervals below:

[image]

Comment: You didnt' define "v"

Comment: $v$ is initial velocity and regard as constant or parameter, the diagram is set to$10$.